# Couldn't enable symbolic links for Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using the Mysql Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB on Windows 7, and when I run the flollowing command `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_symlink';` I get :

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| have_symlink  | NO    |
+---------------+-------+
```

So I want to enable them.
What have I tried ?

- running : `mysql --symbolic-links` yields the following error :
  `mysql: unknown option '--symbolic-links'`
- I've searched for location where a config file might be present so I looked for `my.cnf` and `my.ini` in the following locations :
  `%WINDIR%\my.ini` `%WINDIR%\my.cnf` `\my.ini` `\my.cnf` `%APPDIR%\mysql\my.ini` `%APPDIR%\mysql\my.cnf` `%APPDIR%\mysql\data\my.ini` `%APPDIR%\mysql\data\my.cnf` to not find any file then I've created the following option file to be used when starting the server `my.cnf` with the following command :
  `[mysqld]`
  `symbolic-links`
- I've [made sure that in Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2012/05/07/the-symbolic-link-cannot-be-followed-because-its-type-is-disabled/):

> Local to local symbolic links are enabled.
>    Local to remote symbolic
>   links are enabled.

So what am I doing wrong and how to make the `have_symlink` variable have a value of `yes` ??

**EDIT:**
I've restarted the server after the change to the `my.cnf` file, but without success

**EDIT 2:**
for the first mentioned error, it is because `--symbolic-link` is a server rather than client option, so I would type `mysqld --symbolic-links` and that relieves me of searching any option file, because the command line specified options take precedence.

Answer (score 6):

You've got to do two things:

1. Put `symbolic-links=1` in the configuration file *(`.cnf`)* under `[mysqld]`.
2. Restart the `MySQL` Server.

After restarting, the `have_symlink` value should be `yes`.

---

**Beware:** Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks ([reference](http://answers.wikia.com/wiki/Why_is_it_recommended_to_disable_symbolic_links_in_MySQL)).

Comment: Did you try it in the `.ini` file or the `.cnf` you created?

Comment: in the `.ini` file

Comment: You have to put it in the `.cnf` file.

Comment: I still have `have_symlink` value as `no`

Comment: Well, that's the de facto way to turn it on. If it's not working, then something else is going on with your system that we don't know of. Or perhaps you have placed your `.cnf` file in a wrong directory.

Comment: I'll award you the bounty because you have given the right approach, although it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you @user10089632. I wish I could be of further assistance, but the problem you are facing has probably something to do with your system and it's impossible to tell what could be the underlying cause.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be running MySQL 10

symbolic-links is deprecated as of MySQL 8

https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=8392

```
Symbolic links is defacto disabled on most MySQL distributions, because sample 
configuration files contain:

symbolic-links=0

Since symbolic links allow MySQL to write data to any effective location on the
operating system, it creates two issues:

1) MySQL may be tricked into writing to locations it is not supposed to
2) MySQL may write to a location that has privileges that are too loose, and may 
be tampered with by other users on the operating system.

(MySQL mitigates risk #1 by not overwriting existing files, but the risk still 
remains as an attack vector.)

We therefore decided:

1) Change the compiled default to OFF (aligning with the defacto default)
2) Deprecate and remove this functionality in a future release.

Deprecation of --symbolic-links includes deprecating have_symlink.
```